# What programming language can be run on any operating system without installing any framework?

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a program with C#, but in order to run the application .NET framework is needed and I have no authority to install any program on systems (most of them are XP),

I want to know is there any way to run C# application without .NET framework?(I have searched stackoverflow and google and most of people say NO, but I ask again for a little hope!)

If the answer to this question in NO, what language is very similar to C# and there is no other program to be installed to run. (most of my systems are XP SP1)

Best Regards.

Comment: I'd say write a c++ app or consider if this app can be transformed to a webapplication, though it seems easier to just include the .net framework installer with your distro?

Comment: Do you really mean *any* operating system, or do you mean XP SP1?

Answer (score 4):

Most operating systems come with a C compiler, or one is readily available so you can use that.

I think you're confusing the language with the general availability of libraries and confused by 'framework' too.

In terms of 'any operating system' if you mean mobile phones, embedded systems, Linux, Unix, other *Nixes, workstations, Windows, .. you could find a C compiler for all of those.  Don't expect your programs to have a GUI, though.

Comment: I mean XP, 7, Vista (Computers)

Comment: Any reason this was voted down?

Comment: Those are all the same Operating System - just different versions of Windows.  There are many, many OSes.  If you mean 'windows operating system', or 'modern Windows operating system', say that in the question, and don't use a term like 'any'...  And I don't know what you mean by 'Computers'?  As if mobile phones, Macs, Unix systems aren't?

Answer (score 2):

[Salamander](http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/protector.html) is an obfuscation tool that converts your .NET programs into a native self-contained image. This will run without having to install the framework because everything is bundled together however, if you do so, you'll get huge binaries. I believe even the smallest programs go up by 20-30 MB.

It actually says something about that you need a small run-time component for Salamander itself but they also say that it is to be removed in future versions. While Salamander is a tool for protecting you code it can be used to create self contained .NET applications.

Comment: ..does that really run on Mac, Unix, Linux, embedded systems?

Comment: @Kieren The question does state that he is targeting Windows XP; I don't believe he *really* meant *any* operating system (otherwise I look forward to the GEM version to run on my old Atari...)

Comment: @Kieren No this is a Windows only solution specifically if you insist on using .NET and want to avoid .NET framework installation.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get (all operating systems and C#-like) is C (or perhaps C++) but even then, the differences between the operating systems will cause a lot of handling OS specific stuff.

Answer (score 1):

if all your target machines are XP (win32 or win64 OS) the best language without installation of any framework is native machine code based language which is C++.

it is close to C# in a sense it supports OOP, but is far from C# with its simplicity.

by compiling C++ code with target machine as Windows, it can run without any further requirement on any windows machine.

Comment: Assuming that you have the correct version of the CRT installed, of course...